# Using OpenGL32.dll in WinForms with HDC

Tags: c#, winforms, opengl

I'm trying to do some basic OpenGL with Windows API functions in OpenGL32.dll. How can I create textures and contexts with C# using native API?

For example:

```
    public static IntPtr CreateContext(IntPtr DeviceContext){
        return wglCreateContext(DeviceContext);
    }
```

The problem is I don't know how to use OpenGL with Forms HDC. Any example of HOW to use OpenGL with Windows Forms HDC?

This is what I got, is there something wrong? I can't find any examples or doc about this, all i find is using TAO or openTK.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.EnableNotifyMessage | ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        IntPtr HDC = OpenGL.CreateContext(CreateGraphics().GetHdc());
        OpenGL.EnableDoubleBuffer(HDC);

        OpenGL.DrawRectangle(10, 100, 10, 100);

    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if(m.Msg == WindowsMessages.WM_ERASEBACKGROUND) return;

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }

}

public static class OpenGL{
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    [DllImport( "opengl32.dll" )]
    static extern IntPtr wglCreateContext(IntPtr HDC);

    [DllImport( "gdi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true )]
    static extern bool SwapBuffers(IntPtr hdc);

    [DllImport( "opengl32.dll" )]
    static extern void glRecti(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

    [DllImport( "opengl32.dll" )]
    static extern void glBegin(UInt32 type);

    [DllImport( "opengl32.dll" )]
    static extern void glEnd();

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static IntPtr CreateContext(IntPtr DeviceContext){
        return wglCreateContext(DeviceContext);
    }

    public static Boolean EnableDoubleBuffer(IntPtr DeviceContext){
        return SwapBuffers(DeviceContext);
    }

    public static void DrawRectangle(Int32 X1, Int32 Y1, Int32 X2, Int32 Y2){
        glBegin(GLEnum.POLYGON);
        glRecti(X1, Y1, X2, Y2);
        glEnd();
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public static class GLEnum{
        public static UInt32 POLYGON = 0x0009;
    }


}

public static class WindowsMessages{
    public static int WM_ERASEBACKGROUND = 0x14;
}
```

P.D. DO NOT recommend using TAO or TK, I can't use them, I need to do it natively.

Comment: What do you mean by "natively"?  I can't figure out what that word is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: Well, natively we use GLFW (replaces GLUT), how you would use that with WinForms I do not know because in my experience GLFW creates the window for you not the other way around.

Comment: So, when you say "natively" you mean "using an existing window"?

Comment: By the way, it's faster to use c++/CLI than p-invoke due to the checks; pinning; and marshalling of the latter.  It's also less error prone as you don't have to redefine what are essentially function prototypes in c#

Comment: @DietrichEpp Yes, by natively I mean using Windows OpenGL Client (OpenGL32.dll), which is the default OpenGL C API integrated in Windows. This is fully documented in both OpenGL reference and Microsoft API Reference.

Comment: @Micky Yes, using natively Win32 Handle from Window in WINAPI (I kind of remade this code in C#, but I want this in C#, not C++, it's for a College project): [OpenGL Doc example](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_%28WGL%29)

Comment: @FukzitoFukzi: I think you misunderstand what OpenTK is.  OpenTK is a wrapper for OpenGL on Windows that lets you call the functions in opengl32.dll from C#.  It is not a "non-native" OpenGL implementation or anything like that.  If you use opengl32.dll directly, without a C# wrapper, you are going to be writing a lot of P/Invoke code, which (1) is tricky to do correctly, (2) takes a lot of time, (3) is a menial job, and (4) is completely unnecessary because you can just use OpenTK.  And I checked www.pinvoke.net, but the OpenGL section is empty with just a "TODO" note.

Comment: @FukzitoFukzi: You can see the differences between OpenTK and the C interface to OpenGL.  For example, `glTexImage2D()` in OpenTK: http://www.opentk.com/files/doc/class_open_t_k_1_1_graphics_1_1_open_g_l_1_1_g_l.html#a058cedf9ece6be6b02bedebb82eb01ae and in C: https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml -- it's the *same function*, you're not losing anything by using OpenTK.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I already know the differences, I know TAO is a wrapper of OpenGL, and OpenTK is a yet better wrapper with more support and is more code legible adapted to C#, not like TAO. I know it can be tricky and would take a lot of time instead of using `glutCreateWindow` lol But I want to make this funny, I don't see anything funny on using `glutCreateWindow` (I'm just a student, and I have 6 months to create a simple 3D project but college assignment request is in C#) so I already know I can use TAO or TK, but would it be funny? I could use the 6 months to do my project, instead of 1 :P

Comment: By the way, libraries such as GLFW are _"[modern replacements to GLUT](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/windowtoolkits/)"_.

Comment: So, you *want* to waste time?  It's not going to make you a better programmer.

Comment: @DietrichEpp You call it "waste" time, I call it "make a boring and easy college project funny ans entertained" lol

Comment: You're basically asking how to copy OpenTK.  Go read the source code for OpenTK, copy it that way.  Or read up on P/Invoke and figure it out yourself.